# If $x=[x_1,...,x_n]$ is Multivariate normal, what is the $x_1,...,x_k$ that will maximise $P(x_1,...,x_k , x_{k+1},...x_n| \mu, \Sigma)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

How would you compute the $x_1,...,x_k$ that will maximise $P(x_1,...,x_k ,x_{k+1},...x_n| \mu, \Sigma)$?

if x was 2D then I think the main eigenvector of the covariance matrix at fixed $x_1$ will give you the $x_2$ that maximises $P(x_1,x_2|\mu,\Sigma)$.

However, say for n=3, you know $x_1,x_2$ and you want to know what will maximise $P(x_1,x_2,x_3 | \mu ,\Sigma)$. With $x_1,x_2$ known, you can't be on the eigenvector of the Covariance matrix anymore.

How would you do this for general n?

Comment: What is the definition of $P(x_1,x_2|\mu,\Sigma)$?

Comment: $x = [x_1,x_2]$ is one observation from A 2D multivariate Gaussian. So It's the density at $f(x|\mu,\Sigma)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are dealing with continuous distribution, it is meaningful to study the pdf $f(x_1,\dots,x_k|\mu,\Sigma,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n).$ 
Let us write the vectors $y_1=(x_1,\dots,x_k)^T$ and $y_2=(x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)^T$
For the multivariate normal,

$$\begin{pmatrix}y_1
\\y_2\end{pmatrix}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\begin{pmatrix}\mu_1
\\\mu_2\end{pmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{11} &\Sigma_{12}
\\\Sigma_{21} &\Sigma_{22}\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

where $\mu_1,$ $\mu_2$ are $k\times 1$ and $(n-k)\times 1$ respectively, with $\mu=(\mu_1^T,\mu_2^T)^T.$ Similarly, $\Sigma_{11}$ is $k\times k,$ $\Sigma_{12}=\Sigma_{21}^T$ is $k\times (n-k)$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ is $(n-k)\times (n-k).$
 The required conditional distribution can then be written as

$$f(y_1|\mu,\Sigma,y_2=\mathbf{a})=\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_1+\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(\mathbf{a}-\mu_2),\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}\right)$$

More on this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution).

By the property of multivariate normal distribution, it is now clear that given $(x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)=\mathbf{a}^T,$ the pdf is maximized at the mean $\mu_1+\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(\mathbf{a}-\mu_2).$